# How to add something to the window title

Tags: cocoa, menu, title

I find an function such as Finder or something like that, when you right click on the finder title,the popup item will appear and you can chose something, how can I do this to get that function to my application by Xcode?
thank you very much.

Comment: You need to add a context menu that appears when you right click on the window title.

Answer (score 3):

Set the window's [`representedURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/representedURL) property, and optionally adjust the menu in the window delegate's [`window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/window%3ashouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu%3a).